# Access data from structured fact in Custom Fact plugin

Tags: ruby, puppet, facter

```
# file: module/lib/facter/custom_fact.rb

Facter.add("test_fact") do
  setcode do
      Facter.value(:my_structured_fact::key::key). # This doesn't work
  end
end
```

How can I reference nested levels of structured fact?

Answer (score 1):

Get the structured fact, then use Ruby to access the hash keys/values.

```rb
Facter.value(:my_structured_fact)[key][key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `undef` errors with, if you know that `my_structured_fact` is always a `Hash` (also known in other programming languages as `map` or `dict`)

```rb
Facter.value('my_structured_fact').dig('key', 'key')
```

> *`dig(key, ...) → objectclick` to toggle source
>   Retrieves the value object corresponding to the each key objects repeatedly.*
>   more about [`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig)

I have also heard synonyms for a *structured fact*:

- *complex* fact (vs a *simple* fact)
- a fact with `Hash` value